# SQL TSQL for Workers per Hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014-express

I have a log with fingerprint timestamps as follows:

```
Usr   TimeStamp
-------------------------
 1    2015-07-01 08:01:00
 2    2015-07-01 08:05:00
 3    2015-07-01 08:07:00
 1    2015-07-01 10:05:00
 3    2015-07-01 11:00:00
 1    2015-07-01 12:01:00
 2    2015-07-01 13:03:00
 2    2015-07-01 14:02:00
 1    2015-07-01 16:03:00
 2    2015-07-01 18:04:00
```

And I wish an output of workers per hour (rounding to nearest hour)
The theoretical output should be:

```
 7:00  0
 8:00  3
 9:00  3
 10:00 2
 11:00 1
 12:00 2
 13:00 1
 14:00 2
 15:00 2
 16:00 1
 17:00 1
 18:00 0
 19:00 0
```

Can anyone think on how to approach this as SQL or if no other way, through TSQL?

Edit: The timestamps are logins and logouts of the different users. So at 8am 3 users logged in and the same 3 are still working at 9am. One of them leaves at 10am. etc

Comment: Assuming by the output the timestamps are login/start and logout/end timestamps and the result should contain the number of users active at that hour. Do the timestamp records contain a field that indicate that it's a start of finish or is the only way pairing by 2's ?

Comment: no indicator. only pairing by 2's

Comment: All righty, then I didn't include that for nothing in my answer ;). It looks like most answers didn't realize that the output is the number of active users, not the occurrences of records in that hour (didn't realize that at first before looking at the output). You might want to add that and the start and end situation in your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: me.name was in the right track, but the result is not the correct one. I already posted my own answer. Take a look.

Comment: Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: @HABO, As I understand `sql-server` is  a "Microsoft SQL Server" software and this tag was included

Comment: @Fabio - The _version_ can be quite important. For example, `LEAD`/`LAG` were introduced in SQL Server 2012. The `sql-server-2014-express` tag provides the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final working code:

```
create table tsts(id int, dates datetime)
insert tsts values
(1 ,   '2015-07-01 08:01:00'),
(2 ,   '2015-07-01 08:05:00'),
(3 ,   '2015-07-01 08:07:00'),
(1 ,   '2015-07-01 10:05:00'),
(3 ,   '2015-07-01 11:00:00'),
(1 ,   '2015-07-01 12:01:00'),
(2 ,   '2015-07-01 13:03:00'),
(2 ,   '2015-07-01 14:02:00'),
(1 ,   '2015-07-01 16:03:00'),
(2 ,   '2015-07-01 18:04:00')

select horas.hora, isnull(sum(math) over(order by horas.hora rows unbounded preceding),0) as Employees from

(
select 0 as hora union all
select 1 as hora union all
select 2 as hora union all
select 3 as hora union all
select 4 as hora union all
select 5 as hora union all
select 6 as hora union all
select 7 as hora union all
select 8 as hora union all
select 9 as hora union all
select 10 as hora union all
select 11 as hora union all
select 12 as hora union all
select 13 as hora union all
select 14 as hora union all
select 15 as hora union all
select 16 as hora union all
select 17 as hora union all
select 18 as hora union all
select 19 as hora union all
select 20 as hora union all
select 21 as hora union all
select 22 as hora union all
select 23
) as horas

left outer join 
(
select hora, sum(math) as math from 
    (
    select id, hora, iif(rowid%2 = 1,1,-1) math from 
        (
        select row_number() over (partition by id order by id, dates) as rowid, id, datepart(hh,dateadd(mi, 30, dates)) as hora from tsts 
        ) as Q1
    ) as Q2
group by hora
) as Q3 

on horas.hora = Q3.hora
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9d6f/1/0)

Comment: The running sum over 1/-1 approach instead of using a count is a nice touch :)

Comment: You'll need to be careful with the way you query your data since you've got the rounding thing going on. Since times between 11:30pm and 11:59pm fall into the bucket starting at midnight the following day/date, a "days worth" of data won't line of with the calendar date.

Answer (score 0):

To start with you can use datepart to get hours for the days as following and then use group by user

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE());
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04e00/1)

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(5),DATEPART(HOUR, timestamp)) + ':00' as time,
count(usr) as users
from tbl
group by DATEPART(HOUR, timestamp)
```

Comment: This wont include the missing hours. Just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need a `datetime hour` table to do this.

**Note :** This is just a example of showing how the query should work for one day. Replace the `CTE` with `datetime hour` table. In `datetime hour` table every date should start with `07:00:00` hour and end with `19:00:00` hour

When you want to do this for more than one day then you may have to include the `Cast(dt.date_time AS DATE)` in `select` and `group by` to differentiate the hour belong to which day

```
WITH datetime_table 
     AS (SELECT '2015-07-01 07:00:00' AS date_time 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 08:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 09:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 10:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 11:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 12:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 13:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 14:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 15:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 16:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 17:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 18:00:00' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '2015-07-01 19:00:00') 
SELECT Datepart(hour, dt.date_time), 
       Hour_count=Count(t.id) 
FROM   datetime_table dt 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Yourtable t 
                    ON Cast(t.dates AS DATE) = Cast(dt.date_time AS DATE) 
                       AND Datepart(hour, t.dates) = 
                           Datepart(hour, dt.date_time) 
GROUP  BY Datepart(hour, dt.date_time)
```

- [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9d6ff/5)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to group by hours and date. Check this below query and hope this helps you:

```
Create table #t1
(
usr int,
timelog datetime
)

 Insert into #t1 values(1, '2015-07-01 08:01:00')
 Insert into #t1 values(2,    '2015-07-01 08:05:00')
 Insert into #t1 values(3,    '2015-07-01 08:07:00')
 Insert into #t1 values(1,    '2015-07-01 10:05:00')
 Insert into #t1 values(3,    '2015-07-01 11:00:00')
 Insert into #t1 values(1,    '2015-07-01 12:01:00')
 Insert into #t1 values(2,    '2015-07-01 13:03:00')
 Insert into #t1 values(2,    '2015-07-01 14:02:00')
 Insert into #t1 values(1,    '2015-07-01 16:03:00')
 Insert into #t1 values(2,    '2015-07-01 18:04:00')

Select cast(timelog as varchar(11)) as LogDate, Datepart(hour, timelog) as LogTime, count(usr) as UserCount from #t1
Group by Datepart(hour, timelog), cast(timelog as varchar(11))
```

Answer (score 0):

The harder part is creating the zeros where data is missing. The usual approach is to generate a list of all possible "slots" and then do an outer join to the actual data. I'm assuming that you only want to run this for a single day at a time.

My approach, which is just an example, works because it does a cross join of two tables with 6 and 4 rows respectively and 6 times 4 is 24.

```
select f1.d * 6 + f0.d, coalesce(data.cnt, 0)
from
    (
        select 0 as d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all 
        select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
    ) as f0,

    (
        select 0 as d union all select 1 union all
        select 2 union all select 3
    ) as f1
    left outer join
    (
        select
            cast(datepart(hh, TimeStamp) as varchar(2)) + ':00' as hr,
            count(*) as cnt
        from LOG
        group by datepart(hh, TimeStamp)
    ) as data
        on data.hr = f1.d * 6 + f0.d
```

Comment: you are ignoring who is placing the fingerprint timestamp (usr)

Comment: You do not list usr in your output nor do I see it in the final answer you posted.

Comment: I meant your query does not take usr into account when processing. In the answer its referred to as ID. (its used in the processing but not in the output)

Comment: Actually I re-read the question and noticed that you didn't want a simple count after all. When I posted my answer it wasn't at all clear that you wanted a running tally and that the timestamps represented logins and logouts.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to round up time to the closest hour

```
DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DATEADD(MI, 30, TimeStamp)), 0)
```

As you see first we add 30 minutes to the original time `(DATEADD(MI, 30, TimeStamp))`
This approach will round up `08:04` to `08:00` or `07:58` to `8:00` too.
As I assume some workers can start working little bid early

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DATEADD(MI, 30, TimeStamp)), 0) As FingertipTime
FROM Fingertips
```

You can create a [Computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) if you use rounded timestamp often

```
ALTER TABLE Fingertips ADD RoundedTimeStamp AS (DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DATEADD(MI, 30, TimeStamp)), 0));
```

For comparing timestamps with constants of work hours you can find different methods. I will use a variable of type `TABLE` where i generate work hours for current day
Then using `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` we get quantity of timestamps

```
DECLARE @WorkHours TABLE(WorkHour DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @WorkHours (WorkHour) VALUES
('2015-07-01 07:00'),
('2015-07-01 08:00'),
('2015-07-01 09:00'),
('2015-07-01 10:00'),
('2015-07-01 11:00'),
('2015-07-01 12:00'),
('2015-07-01 13:00'),
('2015-07-01 14:00'),
('2015-07-01 15:00'),
('2015-07-01 16:00'),
('2015-07-01 17:00'),
('2015-07-01 18:00'),
('2015-07-01 19:00')

SELECT wh.Workhour
, COUNT(ft.TimeStamp) As Quantity
FROM @WorkHours wh
LEFT JOIN Fingertips ft ON ft.RoundedTimeStamp = wh.WorkHour
GROUP BY wh.WorkHour
```

Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9655/8)

Answer (score 0):

Many separate parts that have to be glued together to get this done.
First rounding, this is easily done with obtaining the hour part of the date + 30 minutes. Then determine start and end records. If there are no fields to indicate this and assuming the first occurrence of a day is the login or start, you can use row_number and use the odd numbers as start records.

Then start and end have to be coupled, in sql server 2012 and higher this can be easily done with the `lead` function

To get the missing hours a sequence has to be created with all the hours. Several options for this (good link [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)), but I like the approach of using row_number on a table that is sure to contain enough rows (with a proper column for order by), such as sys.all_objects used in the link. That way hours 7 to 19 could be created as: `select top 13 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by object_id) + 6 [Hour] from sys.all_objects`

If there's only one date to check on, the query can simple left join on the hour of the timestamp fingerprints. If there are more dates, a second sequence could be created cross applied to the times to get all dates. Assuming the one date, final code would be:

```
declare @t table(Usr int, [timestamp] datetime)

insert @t values
(1  ,   '2015-07-01 08:01:00'),
(2 ,   '2015-07-01 08:05:00'),
(3 ,   '2015-07-01 08:07:00'),
(1 ,   '2015-07-01 10:05:00'),
(3 ,   '2015-07-01 11:00:00'),
(1 ,   '2015-07-01 12:01:00'),
(2 ,   '2015-07-01 13:03:00'),
(2 ,   '2015-07-01 14:02:00'),
(1 ,  '2015-07-01 16:03:00'),
(2 ,   '2015-07-01 18:04:00'),
(2 ,   '2015-07-01 18:04:00')

;with usrHours as
(
    select Usr, datepart(hour, DATEADD(minute,30, times.timestamp)) [Hour] --convert all times to the rounded hour (rounding by adding 30 minutes)
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by usr order by [timestamp] ) rnr
    from @t times --@t should be your logging table
), startend as --get next (end) hour by using lead
(
    select Usr, [hour] StartHour , LEAD([Hour]) over (partition by usr order by rnr) NextHour  ,rnr
    from usrHours
),hours as --sequence of hours 7 to 19
(
    select top 13 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by object_id) + 6 [Hour] from sys.all_objects
)

select cast([Hour] as varchar) + ':00' [Hour], COUNT(startend.usr) Users 
from hours --sequence is leading
left join startend on hours.Hour between startend.StartHour and startend.NextHour 
                                and rnr % 2  = 1 --every odd row number is a start time
group by Hours.hour
```